# Ionization Rate of Hydrogen Bombarded by Monochromatic Light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I am following section 6.3 of Weinberg's *Lectures on Quantum Mechanics 2nd ed.* to understand how time-dependent perturbation theory can be used to calculate the ionization rate of hydrogen. For monochromatic polarized light, Weinberg gives the differential ionization rate as follows:

$$
d\Gamma(1s \to \vec{k_e}) = \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|U_{e,1s}|^2 \delta(E_\gamma - E_e) \hbar^3 k_e^2 dk_e d\Omega
$$
Here $E_\gamma$ is the energy of the monochromatic light, $\hbar\vec{k_e}$ is the momentum of the (free) electron after the ionization and $1s$ refers to the original electron in the ground state of the hydrogen atom. Here

$$
U_{e,1s} = \frac{8\sqrt{2} i e \cos\theta}{\pi \hbar^{3/2} k_e^5 a^{5/2}} \epsilon
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the strength of the electric field of the monochromatic polarized light and $\theta$ is the angle the ejected electron's momentum makes with the polarization direction of the monochromatic light.

I understand how Weinberg was able to derive this result by reading and computing the mathematics in sections 6.1  through 6.3. However, I was wondering how the derivation would change if the light was monochromatic but unpolarized.

Chapter 9.3 of Griffith's quantum mechanics mentions the following when an atom is bombarded with EM radiation from all directions and with all possible polarizations.
[image]

The averaging was done as follows. This is just the angular average of all possible directions.

[image]

My idea is that the ionization rate for monochromatic and unpolarized light can be determined as follows:

$$
d\Gamma(1s \to \vec{k_e}) = \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}(|U_{e,1s}|^2)_{avg} \delta(E_\gamma - E_e) \hbar^3 k_e^2 dk_e d\Omega
$$

**Is this the correct way to extend the derivation found in Weiberg? If not, what is the correct way to determine the ionization rate?**